# Llenar <select> HTML en Javascript y dejar seleccionada una opción con el Modelo

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Tengo un problema al llenar un combobox en HTML ..
Este lo lleno desde un JS, Hago una consulta a SQL SERVER y lleno las opciones con este código

```
  $.each(json, function (i, row) {
        var $option = $('<option>');

        $option.val(row.id_prioridad);
        $option.html(row.nom_prioridad);
        $('#cb_Priority').append($option);   
    });
```

Y este es el codigo del HTML

```
<select class="form-control" name="cb_Priority" id="cb_Priority" value="@Model.priority" >
</select>
```

Al iniciar el archivo JS, mando llamar la función que llena el combobox, pero queda seleccionado el primer registro del combobox(select) la que le mando en el @model no la detecta

Comment: prueba con un retardo de tiempo, debe ser problema de tiempos de render

Comment: puedes imprimir un console de row .

Answer (score 1):

Intenta dejar seleccionado un option con el valor de tu modelo.

```
$('#cb_Priority option[value=' + @Model.priority + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
```